# select on all columns of a table with 330K row take 6 min

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to retrieve all the columns to get all the row from the table. This is on MS SQL server 2012.

My table info is below:
Number of rows-330K,
Number of columns-18, 
Indexe -Cluster index on ID columns,
Data Space-57MB,
Index Space-10MB,

When I select all the columns from the table is Management Studio, it take around 6 mins to get all the row. It does a cluster index scan. 
What can be done to improve the performance to retrieve the table faster?
My intension is to run it in less than 1 min.

I created this table instead of a view. This table replaces a view. I was thinking that having all the data in table (avoiding join in the view) will improve performance. But it does not. The table was created and data was populated.

[EXECUTION PLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IViEV.jpg)

create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [abc].[abc](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ss_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [Bm] [numeric](16, 3) NULL,
    [Em] [numeric](16, 3) NOT NULL,
    [Bs] [int] NULL,
    [es] [numeric](16, 3) NULL,
    [Series] [int] NULL,
    [pp_NUM] [numeric](16, 3) NULL,
    [dia] [numeric](8, 4) NULL,
    [thickness] [numeric](7, 4) NULL,
    [Grade_Num] [numeric](12, 8) NULL,
    [Rnum] [numeric](13, 8) NULL,
    [Spct] [numeric](14, 2) NULL,
    [Created_By_User_ID] [nvarchar](45) NULL,
    [Created_DateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Mod_By_User_ID] [nvarchar](45) NULL,
    [Last_Mod_DateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Install_Date] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_abc_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please try to put some images, actual results and expected ones, add your query so we can understand your question

Comment: The cited table info is missing.

Comment: What else is happening on the server while you are doing this select statement? Show you query and execution plan as well.

Comment: share table structure and execution plan of your query

Comment: Presumably you are doing select *? What are you doing with it after you select the data? Surely the select query doesn't take that long in SSMS?

Comment: I am not doing select *, I am listing all the columns, so the performance is better. Actually this is newly created table to replace a view. "Select " is taking that long and nothing else is being executed.

Comment: Are you using filter? any condition in where clause? also can you try with Select 100 PERCENT ?

Comment: No filter, no where clause. Selecting all the columns and all the rows.

Comment: Now I added query and execution plan, any ways to improve the performance would be helpful!

Comment: `I am not doing select *, I am listing all the columns, so the performance is better.` No, it's not. Those are the same thing. And if you are returning 330,000 rows to Management Studio, does this really represent the real-world scenario you are trying to test? Are you users really expecting 330,000 rows to come into a grid in SSMS instantly? Are you accounting for the amount of time SSMS will spend rendering all of that data, because it is far from trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If you select all the rows and all the columns, it will always scan the whole table, in this case the clustered index.

There's no way to improve performance, the only option is to return less information so an index can actually help.

Answer (score 1):

If you read all columns and all rows then you need to transport about 56MB from storage to your PC. Typical bottlenecks are:

1. Storage - try to use PAGE compression on the table or create columnstore index
2. Network - upgrade your network or use dedicated connection
3. CPU (not common in this scenario) - add more CPUs

You need to monitor these when the query is running and identify bottleneck.

Comment: Don't forget that rendering that much data in SSMS is not free, either. So both allowing for that time and dealing with the resources available on the client to a 32-bit app...

Comment: Thank you Piotr, Aaron and Luis!

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can simply create a view for this.it will take time to load first time.once query  executed next time execution plan loads directly without worrying about query execution.

Comment: How is that going to help here? They are returning every column and every row.

Comment: Actually I was trying to void a view and getting all the data into a table so that it is fast, but even after getting all the data into the table, to get the records on second run it is taking more than 6 min. And I do not understand why.

Comment: Luis Cazares and Piotr are correct.  This is simply a matter of data bandwidth -- not query plan logic.  Is this server local or remote?  If remote, consider copying the data either local or closer.